Password is not being passed into SSIS Catalog using SSISBuild and SSISDeploy
I'm working to automate our SSIS Deployments using SSISBuild and SSISDeploy using an SSIS Project after it's pulled down from Git Repo.  As far as I can tell it's all setup correct, in SSIS Project both the Project and Solution are setup as "EncryptSensitiveWithPassword" and I've set the same password on Project and Package.  I have a Project Parameter set as Sensitive and entered a password for it under the Staging configuration:


It saves fine, then I run the SSISBuild and Deploy scripts:

C:\SSISDeploy>SSISBUILD.exe
-p:C:\DeploymentTest\DeploymentTestWithPW\DeploymentTestWithPW.dtproj -c:Staging -pp:Test1234 -o:C:\SSISDeploy\Artifact -l:C:\SSISDeploy\Artifact\log.txt
Build started: SQL Server Integration Services project: Full ...
Starting project consistency check ... [CheckConsistency] Trace
information: Will force rebuild package caches [ProjectBuildValidator]
Trace verbose: Checking item Package.dtsx [RefreshCache] Trace
verbose: No previous cache, creating new [Update] Trace verbose:
Loading package to check password against project [WriteToLog] Trace
verbose: 1 cached package info written to log Project consistency
check completed. The project is consistent. File
'C:\DeploymentTest\DeploymentTestWithPW\obj\Staging\DeploymentTestWithPW.dtproj'
get updated. File
'C:\DeploymentTest\DeploymentTestWithPW\obj\Staging\Project.params'
get updated. File
'C:\DeploymentTest\DeploymentTestWithPW\obj\Staging\Package.dtsx' get
updated. Applied active configuration to 'Project.params'. Applied
active configuration to 'Package.dtsx'. DeploymentTestWithPW ->
C:\SSISDeploy\Artifact\Staging\DeploymentTestWithPW.ispac
C:\SSISDeploy>SSISDeploy.exe
-s:C:\SSISDeploy\Artifact\Staging\DeploymentTestWithPW.ispac -d:CATALOG;/SSISDB/Testing;****** -at:WIN -pp:Test1234 -l:C:\SSISDeploy\Artifact\log.txt
Connection string: Data Source=;Initial
Catalog=SSISDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30 Connect to
'' successfully. Load the ispac file
'C:\SSISDeploy\Artifact\Staging\DeploymentTestWithPW.ispac'
successfully. Will deploy
'C:\SSISDeploy\Artifact\Staging\DeploymentTestWithPW.ispac' to
******:/SSISDB/Testing/DeploymentTestWithPW. Start to deploy... Deploy successfully.

All looks good, Project shows up in the SSIS Catalog.  But when I view the password in the Project Configure Parameters it's blank. I know the password won't appear, but generally it's obscured by dots so I know something's there. Post deployment it's completely empty.

Can someone direct me to what I'm missing?  Thanks
